# .setAutoCancel(true) on firebase gets error undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Here is my code for notification

```
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
  .android.setChannelId("QuanLy")
  .setSound("default")
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .android.setSmallIcon("ic_launcher");
```

Press button

```
onPressSave = () => {
    if (alert.length<0) return this.inputAlertView.shake(800);
    const { name, alertTime} = this.state;
    notification.setTitle(name);
    firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(notification, {
      fireDate: alertTime.getTime()
    });
    this.goBack();
  };
```

But the notification didn't disappear after clicked on notification bar. So I add `.setAutoCancel(true)` to the code, like above code.
But I get error

[image]

Please help, I'm so new on React native. Thanks very much

Comment: I found it, because my device is android, so I insert .android.setAutoCancel( true ), it's ok